# Miss rate calculation

Tags: caching, cpu-architecture

I have this problem:
A program that calculates the sum of 128x128 matrix of 32-bit integers (by rows). I have one-way cache that has 8 sets with block size of 64 bytes, considering only the access to the matrix not the instruction.
I should calculate its miss rate.
And also the miss rate by reading the matrix by column. Sorry if there are grammar mistakes, I only translated it to English.

What I've done so far is that (correct me if I'm wrong):

- Integer size = 4B
- 64/4 = 16 (integers inside a block)
- 128/16 = 8 (blocks per row)
- 15 hit and 1 miss (each block)
- 120 hit and 8 miss (each row)
- 960 hit and 64 miss (all the matrix)
- miss rate = 64/1024 = 0.06 = 6%

Comment: Your result is correct for row access: mandatory misses lead to a 1/16 miss rate.

Comment: but column access has the same miss rate

Comment: Not at all. If a cache line correspond to consecutive data in the same line, it cannot correspond to consecutve data in the same column. The miss rate will be much higher for several reasons.

Comment: yes, there will be miss-hit alternate in the firstest column then 15 consecutive hits in the next 15 columns (120 hits) of the first block (it will be repeated 8 times)

Comment: No. Assume element A[0[0] is at some address A (multiple of 64 to simplify) and goes to cache line 0. At which address is A[1][0]?  To which cache line does it correspond?  What happens when the program comes back to first line to pick A[0][1]? Answering these questions gives you the answer.

Comment: A[0][0] -> line 0. A[1][0] -> line 1? A[0][1] -> line 0? If it's like this, then cache line 0 will be overwritten 8 times?

Comment: Almost. A[1][0] -> line 0. &A[1][0]=&A[0][0]+(size of a matrix row)=&A[0][0]+512, and if cache line 0 corresponds to Ad, line 1 corresponds to AD+64... line7 corresponds to Ad+7*64 and line 0 -> Ad+512. A[1][0] goes to line 0 and that is 100% miss rate.